# Return a list of closest numbers from one list compared to another list

Tags: python, list, floating-point, list-comprehension

I have two lists of floats. I'm trying to return the closest elements from my main list when I compare it to a second list. So for example, If the 1st element of vals is closest to the 3rd element of mylist, the 3rd element is appended to a new list, and so on.

```
def closest(lst, K):
  vals = []
  for val in K:
     num = lst[min(range(len(lst)), key = lambda i: abs(lst[i]-val))]
     vals.append(num)
  return vals

mylist = [-0.25, 0.15, 0, -0.3, 0.45, 0.37]
vals = [0.12, 0.4, -0.32]

print(closest(mylist, vals))
This should return:
[0.15, 0.37, -0.3]
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-8d40bd9d3507> in <module>()
     16   return vals
     17 
---> 18 print(closest(mylist, vals))
     19 

<ipython-input-28-8d40bd9d3507> in closest(lst, K)
     12   vals = []
     13   for val in K:
---> 14      num = lst[min(range(len(lst)), key = lambda i: abs(lst[i]-val))]
     15      vals.append(num)
     16   return vals

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Can you more clearly describe your desired behavior? An example of inputs and desired outputs would be best.

Comment: Since you're using Numpy: `np.argmin(lst[:, None] - K, axis=1)`. However it seems that your "lists" have more than one dimension, so that's another issue to sort out.

Comment: @Groger I'm trying to make a new list of numbers as the same length of my secondary list. So for example if the 1st element of vals is close to the 3rd element in mylist, my new list will contain that 3rd element, and so on.

Comment: When I run the code above I get the expected result without an error. I am on Python 3.8 in Windows.  Run `python --version` in the cmd and see what you get.

Comment: @Jortega I guess my function arguments are not actually using. In my actual code the arguments are numpy arrays. I think that's what's causing the error.